# React class component is not updating after making a change in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a total beginner in ReactJS and following an online tutorial, but my code is not behaving like the one in that tutorial. My problem is when I make any changes in the `App.js` file, they are not reflected in browser instead a white & blank screen appears on the browser window. I am using `Class Components`. Another thing is when the same code is written using a `Functional component` the code runs as expected. **Here is my code that is not working**.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component() {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
         <p>Hi, John</p>
         <p>This is another para</p>
         <button>Click to Change</button>
         
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

and **here is the same code using** `functional components` **that is Working.**

```
function App(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
       <p>Hi, John</p>
       <p>This is another para</p>
       <button>Click to Change</button>
       
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As I told I am a beginner, I have not changed anything else then the `App.js`.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
       <p>Hi, John</p>
       <p>This is another para</p>
       <button>Click to Change</button>
       
      </header>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just checked that I was using extra parenthesis in my code. It worked after I reviewed your code.